# Android getColumName and getColumnIndex 

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm an android novice and I have a problem with my cursor. I can't access the data using:
`cursor.get(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));`

I tried the following code to test for an error:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int x = 2;
        Log.i("MyDebug", "Index: " + x);
        Log.i("MyDebug", "Name: " + cursor.getColumnName(x));
        Log.i("MyDebug", "Index again: " + cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(x)));
    }
```

Result from the Debug Monitor:

```
Index: 2 
Name: mainMenu.title 
Index again: -1
```

Shouldn't the result of "Index again" be 2? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`cursor.getColumnIndex()` expects the name of the column, without the name of the table:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("mainMenu.title"); // -1
cursor.getColumnIndex("title"); // 2
```

Comment: That I tried to, but it doesn't work. I get in both cases -1! When I use cursor.getString(2) I get a proper result, so no problem with the cursor itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by giving my columns aliases in my fairly complex query, then I used these aliases as references eg:
The start of my query:

```
SELECT lith.drill_id, lith.depth_from,
...
...
```

`cursor.getColumnIndex("depth_from") gave -1`

Then I added column aliases:

```
SELECT lith.drill_id AS drill_id, lith.depth_from as depth_from,
...
...
```

`cursor.getColumnIndex("depth_from")` then gave the correct value.