# Why is my getColumnIndex() returning -1?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

Ok, so here is my database create statement:

```
create table entry (
 _id integer primary key autoincrement,
 date integer not null,
 checknum integer,
 payee text not null,
 amount integer not null,
 category text,
 memo text,
 tag text
);
```

After the datbase is created, and I make a call like:

```
mChecknum = cursor.getColumnIndex("checknum");
```

mChecknum is -1. I have pulled the database from the device and used SQLite Browser on it, and the checknum field is there.

Block around statement in question:

```
mDbHelper.open();
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAll();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
COL_DATE = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
Log.v("Main:123", "COL_DATE: " + String.valueOf(COL_DATE) );
COL_CHECKNUM = cursor.getColumnIndex("checknum");
Log.v("Main:125", "COL_CHECKNUM: " + String.valueOf(COL_CHECKNUM) );
COL_PAYEE = cursor.getColumnIndex("payee");
```

COL_DATE returns 1 and COL_PAYEE returns 2. Why is COL_CHECKNUM being ignored/passed over?

Comment: Could you post more of the code around mChecknum? Like how cursor gets created and used up until that point?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511894/android-getcolumname-and-getcolumnindex-problem

Comment: Ok, forget it. It was my own oversight I completely forgot to update the fetchAll query to include the new column. Sorry, still new to this.

Comment: Please post the solution so if someone else has this issue they will have the answer

Comment: I think what the OP is saying is that the column in question was not included in his original SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation getColumnIndex was returning error on the column which had name which contained the "." symbol i.e.:

```
int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Item No.");
```

and despite the column "Item No." was inside the cursor (the debugger Watch showed it) trying to get the column index failed.

Answer (score 0):

In my fetch/fetchAll database functions, I forgot to update the query with the new column.

For example, before i added the new column, my fetchAll code looked like:

```
public Cursor fetchAll() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE,
            KEY_PAYEE, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_MEMO, KEY_TAG}, 
            null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + " desc");
}
```

After adding the new column to the database, my fetchAll function looks like:

```
public Cursor fetchAll() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, 
            KEY_CHECKNUM, KEY_PAYEE, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_MEMO, KEY_TAG}, 
            null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + " desc");
}
```